# upgrading wso2 Identity server mapping database

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am following https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromaPreviousRelease-step11  To upgrade Idenity server to upgrade Identity server from 5.2.0 to 5.3.0 .

In the old version p[5.2.0] , custom database used where i pointed conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml , repository/conf/user-mgt.xml Changes to my own cloud database.

Shouldnt i be doing that in the migration ?Should the same files have to be pointed to my cloud database?

Should I do that before i run 
sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity

One more question. Should i always  have to start server using the option Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity . Or is it just one time?

Also should we go through https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager#ConfiguringWSO2IdentityServerasaKeyManager-Step2-DownloadWSO2API-MandWSO2IS  And do each steps even if we are migrating?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would only run -Dmigrate once. To my knowledge, I'd think you would need to configure your master-datasources.xml and user-mgt.xml to point to the same paths that you initially defined in v5.2.0. There aren't a lot of changes that happen in minor updates, so it should be fine.